# Sort matrix according to specific column, and further sort it using another column, while maintaining the first sort order

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A, consist of 3 column. First column is the x coordinate, second is y coordinate, and finally third is a value with respective to that x&y coordinate. A is initially sorted on first column.

```
A=[
-10    15    0.1
-10    9     0.2
-10    17    0.3
  1     0    0.4
  1    -1    0.5
  1    30    0.6
18      1    0.7
18      9    0.8
18    -17    0.9
]
```

How do I further sort it for y column, while still maintaining the order in x column? Expected result:

```
A=[
-10     9    0.2
-10    15    0.1
-10    17    0.3
  1    -1    0.5
  1     0    0.4
  1    30    0.6
18    -17    0.9
18      1    0.7
18      9    0.8
]
```

The length (or block) of the value x won't be necessary three rows (or consistent either) matrix, `-10` can be 5 rows, and `18` can be 15.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [sortrows](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.sortrows.html) for this. In this case, you want to first sort `A` based on the first column and then on the second column:

```
>> sortrows(A,[1,2])

ans =

  -10.0000    9.0000    0.2000
  -10.0000   15.0000    0.1000
  -10.0000   17.0000    0.3000
    1.0000   -1.0000    0.5000
    1.0000         0    0.4000
    1.0000   30.0000    0.6000
   18.0000  -17.0000    0.9000
   18.0000    1.0000    0.7000
   18.0000    9.0000    0.8000
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like my long descriptive title can just be solved using one function.